# How to run a batch file with electron?

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron, electron-builder

I've been trying to find a solution all morning. I've watched numerous tutorials, but I just don't get how this works.

In my Electron program there is a button. When this button is clicked, a batch file (hpm.bat) should be executed.

**In my index.html file I have defined the button:**

```html
<button class="button" onclick="handleButtonClick()" style="background-color: #e24a4a; border: #e24a4a;"\>
```

**In my renderer.js file I have defined the functions of the buttons:**

```js
const childProcess = require("child_process");

function handleButtonClick() {
    const bash_run = childProcess.spawn([C:\Users\NM\Desktop\Electron\hpm.bat]);    
  }

function handleButton2Click() {
    alert('Button clicked!');
  }
```

I tried to implement it according to various instructions from the Internet, but it just doesn't work. The message `alert('Button clicked!');` works well, but I can't run the batch file.

Can someone please explain to me how I can run the batch file `C:\Users\NM\Desktop\Electron\hpm.bat` with Electron?

I tried various codes from Stack Overflow and YouTube.

Comment: Either enable node integration for the renderer (not recommended) or use IPC between renderer and main process. Maybe you can do it via the preload script as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `child_process.spawnSync`:

```js
childProcess.spawnSync("cmd.exe", ["/c", "C:\\Users\\NM\\Desktop\\Electron\\hpm.bat"]);
```

**Note:** I noticed that you didn't quote the file path. It's also a string, so it needs those quotes.

Comment: I just tried your code. That doesn't work for me and I don't understand why.

Comment: @NMA Sorry for escaping issues. Edited and it should work now.